# Вставление картинки черезе bc-img

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend, веб-дизайн

как вставить картинку с матека через bc-img, чтобы она была как на макете, а не обрезана внизу или сверху но при этом не ставить ей реальной высоты картинки, а чтобы она адаптировалась под 100vh?стили

```
.home-page{
    background: url(/img/ap-ui.png) no-repeat center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: contain
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, что такое bc-img? В гугле внятно не гуглится. Во-вторых, при изменении высоты если не обрезать картинку, то что тогда делать?

Comment: @andreymal background-img, то есть мне просто вставлять картинку с height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
????а как же тогда сделать пиксель пёрфект

Comment: Ну если не обрезать, то `background-size: contain` может?

Comment: @andreymal тогда полуается что она обрезается по бокам, как растянуть?

Comment: contain никак не может ничего обрезать, так что непонятно, о чём вы вообще говорите и какой пиксель пёрфект требуется, вероятно вы что-то криво сверстали

Comment: @andreymal добавил картинку в описание, стили `.home-page{
    background: url(/img/ap-ui.png) no-repeat center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: contain
}`

Comment: Ну, на скриншоте я вижу, что она как раз не обрезалась, а вписалась по высоте — после вписывания по бокам осталось свободное место, что логично и правильно, именно так contain и работает. Если вам требуется не это, тогда непонятно что вам требуется

Comment: @andreymal я так понял, если кидают такую картинку и хотят, чтобы она была на весь экран при переходе на сайт, то это сделать нельзя и нужно другое разрешение картинки? и ни о каком пиксель пёрфекте речь не идет?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/300) no-repeat center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```